# UEFI: Boot a specific installation of Windows via bootmgfw

Tags: uefi, bootmgr

I am tasked with upgrading a number of machines to Windows 11. However, some accounting software refuses to work on Windows 11. This is why I need to offer a Windows 10 installation as well. When doing remote administration, I can wake up the system and it will perform a PXE boot (giving me the option to boot into any system remotely). I can chainload `bootmgfw.efi` which will then continue into one of the Windows installations. It would be very helpful if I had control over which Windows installation is being booted. This article gives a nice [overview of the Windows boot procedure](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI-Plugfest-WindowsBootEnvironment.pdf) in UEFI (via [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1261860/difference-between-bootmgr-efi-and-bootmgfw-efi)).

When [examining the efivars](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666459/what-is-the-meaning-of-efibootmgr-v-after-efi-file-path), I noticed that bootmgr seems to accept a parameter named BCDOBJECT. It looks like one can specifiy the UUID of the BCD entry bootmgr is to boot.
This mechanism apparently is used to start [Windows Recovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-hardware-recovery-button-to-start-windows-re). However, I found no clear source of documentation regarding this feature, not even in [this detailed post](https://news.saferbytes.it/analisi/2013/10/windows-uefi-startup-a-technical-overview/). Is there any option to tell `bootmgfw.efi` which BCDOBJECT to use via UEFI?

Related questions on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192128/booting-multiple-copies-of-windows-via-grub and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328223/getting-rid-of-the-windows-boot-manager-when-dual-booting/1328229
A similar question: [Make Linux GRUB run directly multiple Windows systems](https://superuser.com/questions/1756042/make-linux-grub-run-directly-multiple-windows-systems)

Comment: Does the software not work in Compatibility Mode? While I can't answer your question, if you add both to the BCD Store, the Windows bootloader will give a 30s boot selection menu when the Windows bootloader loads. I've never tried PXE boot, so the following may not be helpful: [BCDOBJECT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bcd/bcdobject) and [`BcdEdit /Set`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--set)

Comment: I have had no success with compatibility mode. The Software obtains it license from a USB dongle. It seems that it won't work with Windows 11 and also not with VMs. The boot selection menu is very handy for selecting the system – but it requires local user interaction. However, quite often I am not even in the same city when doing administrative tasks remotely. Of course, I can boot a random system and if it is the wrong one, change the default, then reboot. Though that is rather cumbersome.

Comment: This may be a remedial question - does booting WinPE via PXE boot not allow using `BcdEdit /Set` to boot to the OS version installed? This may be more convoluted, but if not, can be automated by editing WinPE's [`Windows\System32\StartNet.cmd`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wpeinit-and-startnetcmd-using-winpe-startup-scripts) to run a script stored within WinPE's `boot.wim`  to set the OS version to boot to via `BcdEdit /Set`, then reboots via `wpeinit reboot` _(modify `StartNet.cmd` and add script by mounting WinPE `boot.wim` via `Dism /Mount-Image`)_

Comment: @JW0914 Convoluted indeed – but automatable. I would take that as an okay-ish answer. :)