# Why would computer technician want my bitlocker key after GPU repair & SSD replacement? (Laptop)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, bios, bitlocker, windows-key

My laptop has been in the local repair store now for three months - the GPU was resoldered and stencilled. During the repair I damaged the SSD at home and the laptop wouldn’t boot. They tried to repair the SSD (taking a week) but it’s a no fix and it was returned to me. Fast forward to today:

The techie told me I need to install a new SSD, OK. He asked for the bitlocker key - which didn’t sound right to me because I thought that was used to access the hard drive but we’re using a new SSD? He told me that the key is needed because it stops theives from stealing machines and just replacing the SSD. He also said the SSD is paired to the BIOS chip and that to reuse my windows key stored in the BIOS he doesn’t want to wipe it?
Is this correct?

I’m worried maybe he cloned my hard drive and wants the key to steal my data. Or does he have legitimate reasons?

TLDR:
Techie wants bitlocker key to install new SSD and use same windows product key from BIOS after physical GPU repair and SSD replacement. (After having my SSD in his possession for a week)

Comment: There is no legitimate reason to provide this individual your BitLocker Recovery key.

Comment: Did the technician clone your system disk to a new SSD? If he did, then he would need to boot in order to test, and so would then need this key.

Comment: @harrymc well he had it in his possession for a week as it was bent (i didn’t look after it while GPU was being repaired) and he was trying to fix it. He could have coined it without my consent?

Comment: I added an answer that tries to make sense of the situation.

Comment: I would not work from the assumption that the technician is using the correct terminology in describing what is needed.

Comment: "use same windows product key from BIOS" - The Windows key is NOT stored in the BIOS.  Far to many people make this critical mistake. The key is stored in the ACPI table, while the ACPI table is linked to the device's firmware, the ACPI table is actually independent from the actual firmware. I go back to the fact there is absolutely no reason to provide the BitLocker recovery key to this individual, the problem they face of installing Windows on a new SSD, can be solved without knowing the BitLocker recovery key.

Answer (score 14):

This makes no sense whatsoever.

The BitLocker key is tied to the SSD. It has no relation to the Windows license.
New SSD doesn't have BitLocker. And when, after installing a fresh Windows, you encrypt it using BitLocker you may use the same PIN for BitLocker, but internally the new BitLocker setup will have a different, fresh BitLocker master-key.

If the motherboard isn't replaced a fresh Windows 10 (or 11) installation will automatically re-activate its license as soon as it is connected to the internet. (Regardless if the login is a local user-account or a Microsoft LiveID).

So there is no way a service-tech needs your old BitLocker code.

Comment: Bitlocker can be bound to a set of TPM PCRs, a set that usually includes the measurement of the hardware configuration. When this is true, HW replacement will invalidate the measurement and Bitlocker will require the *recovery* key (which is not stored anywhere in the original disk unless OP saved it to a file) to rebound to the new measurement. This can happen if the technician cloned the old SSD as I would expect. OP can type the recovery key themself at the store.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - If that were the case it is trivial to clear the stored keys. Which goes back to the point, if the SSD that was encrypted is NO-OP, then there is no legitimate reason to provider the BitLocker recovery key. If the original disk no longer exist, wiping the keys stored in the TPM, will allow the author to use BitLocker on the new disk.

Answer (score 7):

I fail to see how your BitLocker key would help. If some data has been salvaged and needed to be decrypted, sure, to replace with a new device, I'm not even aware of any way you could tell Windows to use a specific key.

Let's see it another way. Your HDD/SSD became corrupted and you need to reinstall Windows. Windows won't install itself encrypted at first. So why would having that key be necessary to install a new OS?

So far I'm not aware of PC computers were you can't replace a bit of hardware unless you have some security key.

Sounds dodgy, now in IT, I've heard lots of people say things they believed were true.

The closest thing I can think of is your Windows "digital entitlement" which is somewhat tied to your hardware, if you replace too much hardware, the license will at least need to be re-activated. He might think having the bitlocker key will reduce the chances of that happening (which to the best of my knowledge it doesn't).

My advice: don't give it. I actually wouldn't even expect most people to have it... (OK it might be saved in the MS account)

Comment: *if you replace too much hardware* ... As long as you don't replace the motherboard you NEVER need to re-add any Windows OS license.

Comment: @ChanganAuto In the olden days (WinXP etc), swapping out a hard drive or graphics card was 'too much hardware' and you had to get a new licence.

Comment: Even in those days all it took was a call to the local Microsoft tech support.

Comment: @ChanganAuto As I said, you might need re-activation. Not a new license.

Answer (score 3):

*He also said the SSD is paired to the BIOS chip and that to reuse my windows key stored in the BIOS he doesn’t want to wipe it? Is this correct?*

That is correct. Windows stores keys in the TPM.  If you wish to use those keys you must have the TPM password.

If you wish to do a clean install of Windows, you can discard those keys, but that does mean that any other keys you have installed will also be discarded.  In particular, if you are a business user, using your laptop as a smart card, you're going to loose that key.

On the other hand, if all you've got to worry about is encrypted, replaceable files such as media on the discarded SSD, then you can just do a clean install.

If you want to use your existing MS Windows license for a clean install, you may have to give your MS account login password to the tech, or do your own Windows installation.

[Windows TPM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/hardware-security/tpm/how-windows-uses-the-tpm)

Comment: MS is occasionally horrible about keeping links in the same place. https://archive.ph/QlWXP is an archived copy of said link.

Comment: So maybe he wants the bitlocker key for legit reasons? After all resoldering the GPU could have prompted this. The techie said he will do it in front of me and he doesn’t have my hard drive and it’s probably unlikely he cloned it?

Comment: Hardware change requires re-activation. Re-activation requires license key. License key requires TPM or Product key. Does your laptop have an associated product key? You may be able to get product key from original manufacturer. Did you register laptop with original manufacturer? Is there anything else in TPM?

Comment: @user165568 IIRC the TPM is an HSM, not a GP storage unit. It can generate keys, export them, decrypt given secrets, and so on but not store arbitrary information securely. AFAIK Windows stores OEM activation keys in the ACPI tables and not in the TPM (which is not even possible IIRC). Probably OP completely misunderstood the technician and it may turn out that they actually wanted a Windows license key because they reinstalled Windows from scratch on the new SSD.

Comment: @margeret-bloom my understanding is that TPM 2 protects the Advanced Configuration tables.  I may be wrong about what parts of the ACPI tables are protected, but I think the end result is the same: Windows won't work without clean install or TPM.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I very much like your hypothesis, this would make sense. I'm not aware of the TPM playing any part in the activation, and indeed, it doesn't store data (you store the data outside, after it encrypted it)

Comment: @user165568 I very much doubt the TPM protects ACPI tables. It can be that as part of secure boot, some registers (the PCRs) are sealed using state of the ACPI tables. TPM in itself does not protect anything, it accepts letting you access some information if it is in a known state.

Comment: @Ben - "After all resoldering the GPU could have prompted this." - The work with the GPU would NOT have resulted in a configuration change. The SSD being damaged, and the system configured to use BitLocker with the key stored in the TPM, would be the configuration change.  In that case since the original SSD is damaged, wiping the key from the TPM is the solution, there is no legitimate reason to provide the BitLocker recovery key to the technician.

Comment: @user1532080 - The TPM does NOT protect the ACPI table.  The author's problem is they were using BItLocker, their storage device failed, and now have to wipe the keys from the TPM where the keys were stored to reinstall Windows.  The activation process when dealing with Windows 10+ is automatically.  Hardware changes are no longer a concern, besides the GPU changing wouldn't require Windows to be reactivated.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: TPM1 and TPM2 has a small amount of general purpose storage ("NV indices") which can be used to directly store a few kB of data, and even to lock it to PCRs and/or PIN (same policies as when using the TPM for encryption), but Windows doesn't use it for anything at all, as far as I've seen. Usually the firmware doesn't, either, though I've heard of HP using it to store the firmware admin password or something like that. But most uses of the TPM are only "sealing" where the data is encrypted and returned to OS for storage.

Answer (score -2):

Ask them to do a sector-by-sector copy to a larger replacement SSD and expect that you may need to fix the boot loader after this and enter your BitLocker key after SSD replacement, since they won't be able to ensure that it boots.  The tech may also want to test the GPU in Windows.

Answer (score -3):

The only way this makes sense is if the old disk was replaced,
so the new disk is empty, yet the bitlocker key is still
found in the TPM so the BIOS is still insisting
on it, although the new disk isn't encrypted at all.
However, the technician cannot access the disk without
the password in order to install Windows.

If you know the password, giving it might help the technician,
although the whole situation is unclear to me and I have
doubts that this will help.

Otherwise, the simplest solution to use the new disk
would be to clear the TPM.
This would require knowledge of the exact model of your
motherboard and your BIOS version,
but in general this is an option inside the BIOS, perhaps found
inside a "TPM security" section.

---

Since I was attacked and this answer was downvoted on the basis
that the UEFI has nothing to do with Bitlocker, here are some
facts that will throw some light on the question.

1. I was criticized for saying that the Windows bootloader
   uses the UEFI to turn off Bitlocker, so here are some facts about
   the sizes of the involved softwares as gathered for one Windows 10
   computer:

   - The Windows bootloader (`bootmgfw.efi`) :  1 590 640 bytes
   - The Windows Bitlocker interface (`manage-bde`) : 222 KB
   - The UEFI download file (`BIOS_IMG.rcv`) : 27.06 MB

   This small bootloader is also called "stub" in some Microsoft
   documentation, and it's clear that it must rely heavily on
   services supplied by the UEFI.
2. In fact, the
   [Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) Specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_10_Aug29.pdf)
   says this very clearly in section "2.1.3 UEFI OS Loaders":

> A UEFI OS loader is a special type of UEFI application that normally takes over control of the system from firmware
> conforming to this specification. When loaded, the UEFI OS loader behaves like any other *UEFI application* in that
> **it must only use memory it has allocated from the firmware and can only use UEFI services and protocols to access
> the devices that the firmware exposes**.

3. A certificate may contain information identifying its
   intended usage. For example, the Microsoft article
   [BitLocker group policy settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-group-policy-settings#reference-validate-smart-card-certificate-usage-rule-compliance)
   says:

   > The object identifier is specified in the extended key usage (EKU) of a certificate. BitLocker can identify which certificates can be used to authenticate a user certificate to a BitLocker-protected drive by matching the object identifier in the certificate with the object identifier that is defined by this policy setting.

   This means that it's possible for the UEFI to identify
   Bitlocker-intended keys inside the TPM (unfortunately
   not much information is publicly available about which are
   the exact mechanisms used by Bitlocker for the TPM).

It can be concluded that indeed it's the UEFI that controls all
device accesses and every resource request issued by the
bootloader. It can be said that the UEFI is the guarantee that
Secure Boot is indeed secure - for each and every action,
the bootloader must pass through the UEFI.
This certainly includes verifying digital signatures and
also Bitlocker and TPM.

I believe that I have answered here all the criticism that was
directed at me in the comments.

Comment: Even that still doesn't make sense, as TPMs don't work that way. They don't deal with disk encryption nor even know what a disk is.

Comment: No, but the BIOS does.

Comment: Would him doing this require a new windows activation key though??

Comment: *Would him doing this require a new windows activation key though??* NO!

Comment: Why downvote an answer which could be helpful because someone doesn't like its wording? This is not very serious.

Comment: Upvoted. Because I do think @harrymc has the correct answer.  TPM was sort of my hunch too. [Bitlocker does use TPM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-tpm-705f241d-025d-4470-80c5-4feeb24fa1ee). But I think the tech might be confused trying salvage the new disk. Either do a sector-by-sector copy and see if it just works. Or just wipe the TPM memory and re-install Windows.

Comment: @selbie: The thing is, a TPM stores data for BitLocker but doesn't store any part _of_ BitLocker. All actual program code that would deal with BitLocker (whether with its TPM usage or its recovery key usage) is either part of the Windows bootloader or becomes part of the disk if OPAL is in use, but either way goes away with the disk; there's no part of the BIOS that would "insist" on it. So it's not really about wording, it's about the fundamental concepts.

Comment: @harrymc he said something about without the bitlocker key he will need to wipe the bios chip and it will take longer?

Comment: @Ben: Did he already try to clear out just the TPM ? I hope you don't need the data that was on the old disk. Note that once installed, Windows will activate itself by digital entitlement of the rest of your hardware (as long as the motherboard is not also replaced). Note that I'm not impressed with a technician that takes 3 months to fix a computer.

Comment: @harrymc There is nothing important on the old disk just college work which is already backed up. He said the pc booted but had no Wi-Fi or something. He also said with bitlocker key it’s an easy fix but said if I don’t have it he will have to wipe the chip?

Comment: @Ben: I don't know which chip is meant, but I'm not sure that after 3 months he really knows what the problem is. I stand behind my answer.

Comment: @u1686_grawity: You're off-subject here. Secure Boot is a feature of the UEFI, requiring it to verify the digital signature of the boot loader *and* of the OS kernel. The bootloader is found in the unencrypted EFI partition, but the OS kernel is in an encrypted one. The UEFI need then to turn bitlocker off to verify the kernel. The TPM standard also requires the UEFI to be able to wipe clean the TPM and to enable the user to enter a new OS digital signature into the TPM. ...

Comment: ... If you don't believe me, study the [Secure the Windows boot process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/system-security/secure-the-windows-10-boot-process) and especially the section "Trusted Boot". Depending on the UEFI implementation, the UEFI will require at some stage the bitlocker password to be able to boot the disk.

Comment: @harrymc: I know how Secure Boot works and how it interacts with BitLocker and TPM, because I've actually made my own tools to interact with them, I've read the actual data that gets stored in TPMs, and I know for sure that "enter a new OS digital signature into the TPM" is not how Secure Boot works and that it's not UEFI that needs the BitLocker password. (The bootloader can call back into UEFI services if it needed to do SB verification; but as the page you linked to says, "The *bootloader* verifies the digital signature of the Windows kernel before loading it.")

Comment: @u1686_grawity: It stands to reason that the bootloader uses UEFI services to verify the kernel.

Comment: Possibly (although I highly suspect that Windows does verification internally), but UEFI's SB verifies against a _generic_ CA certificate entry (which is the main reason why BitLocker interacts with SB at all – it could use the TPM without SB, but _then_ BitLocker would be forced to "check a specific signature"). In nearly all cases with Windows PCs, the SB data remains unchanged across reinstalls – just the two generic MS CA entries in it, and possibly some entries that specifically revoke old versions, but nothing that "verifies" a specific version, much less a specific install.

Comment: @u1686_grawity: You're very wrong here as regarding the bootloader.

Comment: You're very wrong here as regarding "For Bitlocker to support the TPM, the UEFI is a requirement", regarding the relevance of the software (bootmgfw isn't even the bootloader), and regarding pretty much everything else.

Comment: @u1686_grawity: OK, continue the ignore the facts. Just try to use Bitlocker with TPM on a legacy BIOS computer.

Comment: I'm not ignoring them, I'm stating that they're either misinterpreted, at best, or flat out wrong. I *have* tried using BitLocker with TPM on a legacy BIOS computer. ([As has Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/data-protection/bitlocker/)) I've also used TPMs "by hand" for various purposes, even on pure-BIOS systems that had TPM1.2. I literally have practical experience in this area.

Comment: @u1686_grawity: I admit error in this case, this was sometime ago said to be different, deleted. But see about [bootmgfw.efi](https://superuser.com/questions/1261860/difference-between-bootmgr-efi-and-bootmgfw-efi). And the rest is either facts or straight from the documentation. I'm out of this.